# onmouseover when replacing an image

Tags: javascript, css, events, dom-events, onmouseover

What I am doing is replacing an image with another image (actually just changing its display and src properties). If I remove the if conditions, then `onmouseover` works, but other events do not work as I want them to work.

```
<strong onmouseover='if(this.lastChild.style.display=="none")    {this.lastChild.style.display="inherit";}'     onmouseout='if(this.lastChild.style.display=="inherit"){this.lastChild.style.display="none";}' onclick='menuArrow(this, "<?php echo site_url(); ?>")'><?php the_sub_field('feature_title'); ?> <img id="menu-arrow" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/orange/img/triangle-down.png" onclick="menuArrow()"></strong>

    function menuArrow(obj, url)
    {
        if(obj.lastChild.src == (url + "/wp-content/themes/orange/img/triangle-down.png")){
            obj.lastChild.src = url + "/wp-content/themes/orange/img/triangle-up.png";
            obj.lastChild.style.display = "inline";
        } else {
            obj.lastChild.src = url + "/wp-content/themes/orange/img/triangle-down.png";
            obj.lastChild.style.display = "inherit";
        }
    }
```

I am using `display` property `inherit` to flag the menu option as not selected. `none` property means that it was not selected and the mouse pointer is not on it. `inline` means that the menu option is selected. Basically, when the page loads, no image is displayed. Once mouse pointer is on a menu option, then first image appears. If a client clicks on the menu option, then the first image changes to the second.

The problem is that if I do not click on any menu option, then no image appears (even though `display` is set to `none`). As I mentioned before, if I mingle with if statements, it starts to work, but if a client moves his pointer away, the image disappears even though it is selected.

Comment: Please don't use inline event handlers except for very small examples. It is unreadable in your code.

Comment: I understand, but these are just if statements with one line.